# Emoji Autocomplete like github?

Tags: javascript, jquery, emoji

https://github.com/blog/1289-emoji-autocomplete

I've been searching for a similar emoji autocomplete experience like github has. However, the results are little - does anyone know of a javascript/jquery library that facilitates emoji autocomplete?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Little late but this should work https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete